# How to import a .slk file in python

Tags: python, import, python-import, slk

I have a .slk file that I couldn't import in python, I used the following code but it doesn't work:

```
from sylk_parser import SylkParser
parser = SylkParser("fileName.slk")
```

I got this error:

```
OverflowError: mktime argument out of range
```

Thanks for your help!